# How do I make a work command (PyCharm 2020.3.2 Python 3.9)

Tags: python, discord.py, python-3.9

I created this Economy category for my bot which currently has 2 commands. Balance and Transfer. I am trying to add a work command and I came up with this:

```
@commands.command()
    async def work(self, ctx):
        id = str(ctx.message.author.id)
        amount = {random.choice(x)}
        amounts[id] += amount
        await ctx.send(f"You worked at a dumpster and earned {random.choice(x)}")
```

but PyCharm came up with this error:

```
Ignoring exception in command work:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MainAccount\PycharmProjects\Cat_Bot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\MainAccount\PycharmProjects\Cat_Bot\cogs\cog_economy.py", line 85, in work
    amounts[id] += amount
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'set'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MainAccount\PycharmProjects\Cat_Bot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 902, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\MainAccount\PycharmProjects\Cat_Bot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 864, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\MainAccount\PycharmProjects\Cat_Bot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'set'
```

Could someone help me to fix this? And please explain the problem if you have the answer

Comment: For full cog, refer to this page:
(https://paste.pythondiscord.com/vevanutapa.py)

Comment: What does your `amounts` variable looks like? Same for `x`?

Comment: @Mr_Spaar It is referenced in the beginning of the file. It is: ```amounts = {}
```

Comment: It is supposed to reference peoples economy accounts if the json file isn't found.

Comment: And what about `x`? Is it a list of sets?

Comment: check (https://paste.pythondiscord.com/vevanutapa.py). It has the full code there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error comes from here:

```py
amount = {random.choice(x)}
```

You're defining `amount` as a `set` so adding it to an `int` causes an error.
What you simply have to do is removing the curly brackets:

```py
@commands.command()
async def work(self, ctx):
    id = str(ctx.message.author.id)
    amount = random.choice(x)
    amounts[id] += amount
    await ctx.send(f"You worked at a dumpster and earned {amount}")
```

I've also replaced `random.choice(x)` to `amount` in your message so it won't display a different amount than the money the member really earned.

Comment: Still has a problem: (https://paste.pythondiscord.com/mufumufocu.sql)

Comment: Well I can't do much about it, it just means that your user doesn't have any account.

Comment: No, sorry. I forgot to reload the bot. Your answer was correct.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have an indentation problem. (Ignore if that problem was caused due to copy-pasting)

try amounts[id] += int(amount)

Also, x is not defined...

Comment: x is defined. It is supposed to be the random amount for what is supposed to be added to the player account

Comment: did you try 
int(amount)
?

also, can you show me what x looks like?

if x = [1,2,3] its fine, but if x = ['1','2','3'] it wont work because '1' is a string and 1 is an integer. '1'+'1' is 11, and 1 + 1 is 2. I hope you understand